# How to stop a recursive generator in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, generator

Let's say I'm using a recursive generator to traverse a binary tree and I'd like the traversal to stop when a certain condition is satisfied:

```py
def traverse(node):
    if node is None:
        return

    yield from traverse(node.left)

    if node.val == 5:
        return # return only skips node 5, but doesn't fully stop iteration. What does?

    yield node.val

    yield from traverse(node.right)
```

How do you achieve this?

I tried raising `StopIteration`, but that results in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in `traverse` typically, you'd have the code iterating it `break` the loop when it reaches the value to stop at. If it must do it this way, you can write a wrapper (non-recursive) generator that does the same thing.

Comment: I agree with ShadowRanger. The function that consumes `traverse()` should control when the iteration stops rather than doing it in `traverse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate stop and iteration into two:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def traverse(node, stop_value):
    yield from takewhile(lambda x: x != stop_value, _traverse(node))

def _traverse(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    yield from _traverse(node.left)
    yield node.val
    yield from _traverse(node.left)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should control when the iteration stops from whatever code calls `traverse()`:

```
def traverse(node):
    if node is None:
        return

    yield from traverse(node.left)

    yield node.val

    yield from traverse(node.right)
```

```
for n in traverse(node):
    if n == 5:
        break
```

Comment: That makes sense. I think you and @Marat are saying more or less the same thing. However, since I'm looking for an encapsulated solution, I believe his answer is more inline with what I'm trying accomplish. Thanks for answering though.